# how to store dynamic button text

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have below code and i would like to get the texts of dynamic created buttons on the server side which is clicked however on the second click of the button,the button is disabled and i dont wanna have its text property.

this is the code how i create dynamic buttons with the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofplants; i++)
    {
       builderchart.Append("<th class=style8>");
      builderchart.Append("<input type='button' id='btn" + i.ToString() + "' value='" + dtplants.Rows[i][0] + "' style='width:55px;' class='inputbutton'>");
                        builderchart.Append("</th>");
    }

   .is-highlighted {
    background-color:#6FA478;

        $(function () {
            $('input[type=button]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).toggleClass('is-highlighted');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Do you mean on the second click of the same button, it's disabled? Where in the code are you disabling the button? Or do you mean you want a seperate button to post the form with the list of `.is-highlighted` values?

Comment: ı dont disable i just remove the css property with toggleclass so this means user doesnt want that button information to show in the chart because on the first click bckground of the button is changed to green so it means it is selected but on the second click button visual change to its default proerties so this means it is not selected

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the button to be active on the first click, use the jQuery method `one`.

```
 $(function () {
        $('input[type=button]').one('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('is-highlighted');
        });
    });
```

// Edit

If you're looking to remove the 'text' on the second click, or add new text:

```
          $(function () {

             var count = 1;

             $('input[type=button]').on('click', function (e) {

                 e.preventDefault();

                  count +=1;

                  if( count % 2 === 0 ){

                      $( this ).prop( 'value', 'New Text' )
                               .css( 'background-color', 'green');


                 } else {

                     // Do Something else

                 }
           });
       });
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but using the above, you can keep track of the number of 'clicks' and then apply some action based on the count.

// Edit 02 - Rough, but should work

```
      $(function () {


        var 
        count = 1,
        text;


         $( 'input[type=button]' ).on('click', function (e) {

         e.preventDefault();

           count+=1;

          if( count % 2 === 0 ){

              text = $( this ).val();

               $( this ).prop( 'value', 'New Text' )
                        .css( 'background-color', 'green' );

              $.post( 'some.php', { value: text }, function( data ){ 

               // Do Something

              }


             } else {

              text = $( this ).val();     

              $( this ).prop( 'value', 'default' )
                       .css( 'background-color', '' );


              $.post( 'some.php', { value: text }, function( data ){ 

                  // Do Something else


              }




             }

       });
   });      ​
```

Comment: I want to draw a chart according to clicked buttons (text information) and send this text information to SQL stored procedure,but user can select buttons with the first click but then maybe change his mind and second click on the button not to select it (remove css  with background green),i want to have these selected buttons text information and store in the datatable or someweher else

Comment: Still not 100% sure on what you're trying to achieve, but you should be able to use jQuery 'Post'— check Edit 02

Comment: ı still can not solve the problem how to get the values(text) of the buttons and send it to SQL stored procedure.Can anybody help me?